# Getting filenames matching an extension using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a HTML page using `BeautifulSoup` which has text files, ending with the `.txt` extension. I want to parse the HTML, and fetch the string that ends with `.txt`.

All such strings are within a `<a href>` tag and here are some examples:

`<a href = "foo.txt">`

`<a href = "bar.txt">`

How do I get the `foo.txt` and `bar.txt`.

I did this:

`>>> links = soup.findAll('a')`

But I can't find how to extract the complete string... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BeautifulSoup accepts regexps as parameter form `find()` and `findAll()`
This should work:

```
links = soup.findAll(href=re.compile("\.txt$"))
```

Comment: I think it should be : `soup.findAll('a' , href=...`

Comment: Hmm. What is the difference (if any), between what vartec and mouad have suggested.

Comment: @A A: My suggestion actually search for all the `a` tags that have `href ="*.txt"` , @vartec solution check for all the tags that have `href="*.txt"`.

Comment: @A: my version in theory would catch any tag with `href` attr. Thing is, in HTML the only tag with `href` is `<a>`

Comment: @vartec, @mouad: Oh ok! So that is a non issue. One thing I don't understand is that, even in the case of BeautifulSoup, we are using a regular expression. So why not just use it in the first place directly?

Comment: @A A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @A: because such using Soup, you only regexp contents of `href`. To have regexp on whole document (w/o Soup) would be extremely complicated and not as efficient

Comment: Aah ok. I get it. Thanks. I just tried it using that and see where I was wrong.